# How to delete all SPANs?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove all occurrences of `<SPAN>` and `</SPAN>` from a given text.

For example:

```
<span>Пн - Пт: 09:00-18:00</span><span>Сб: 09:00-13:00</span><span>Вс: выходной</span>
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
phonecatControllers.filter('htmlToPlaintext1', function() {
    return function(text) {
        return  String(text).replace('</span><span>', ' ');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For removing span with content:

```
String(text).replace(/<span>.*<\/span>/,'');
```

or if you want to leave content:

```
String(text).replace(/<span>([^<]+)<\/span>/g,'$1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could chain a couple more replaces to remove the starting and ending tag:

```
return String(text)
    .replace('</span><span>', ' ')
    .replace('<span>', '')
    .replace('</span>', '');
```

Comment: Not quite right because he wants to insert spaces between the closing and opening spans.